# Patch requirements for Symantec Antivirus on Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, patching, anti-virus

This is a long shot, but... is anyone aware of the patch requirements for a SharePoint 2010 Foundation farm to install Symantec antivirus (the SharePoint specific app, not endpoint)?

We have a 2010 Foundation farm that has never been patched (I call it 'the fossil'), because it runs a lot of fragile custom code (used for interfacing with Documentum) and workflows.

Symantec's documentation I can get is woefully silent on the matter, and their tech support just push me back to the reseller we use (who told us to talk to the vendor, obviously).

I could install the trial in test but just seeing if I can get a quick answer because it'd take a while to get the client to snapshot it etc (we don't control the infra layer, just the app).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience their is no such requirement when you patching the Antivirus software. Our engineers applied the patches all the time on our sharepoint server for Symantec.

Only thing you have to make sure that they exclude certain folders from AV scanning. [here is the KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/952167/certain-folders-may-have-to-be-excluded-from-antivirus-scanning-when-you-use-file-level-antivirus-software-in-sharepoint)

But if you have an opportunity to test it in different farm then do the testing 1st.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting - what I mean is, in order to install Symantec for Sharepoint (not endpoint) on a Sharepoint 2010 Foundation farm, what patch level does Sharepoint itself need to be at?

Comment: What will Symantec do? Scanning files on Uploading or downloading? or just server protection?

Comment: It will be scanning the up and downloads as the Forefront for Sharepoint agent would do (i.e. as a Windows Service targeting database BLOB transactions, not endpoint files), before it was discontinued.

Comment: in either case, their is no such requirement from SharePoint side...as you asked about patch level. SharePoint or Symantec dont care about the versions or patch.